# Method that can take lists of 2 different types in Java

Tags: java, generics

I want to iterate to through 2 lists and find a value. I'm trying to combine these functions into 1 function, but not sure if possible. Can this be done?
Iteration of List< Student > looks something like

```
for (Student student : studentList){
    if (obj.value() == -1){
        return obj.value();    
}
}
```

Iteration of List< Teacher > looks like

```
for (Teacher teacher : teacherList){
    if (obj.val() == -1){
        return obj.value();    
}
}
```

NOTE: the functions for object A and B retrieve the same value, but they have different function names, hence the .val() vs .value()

Can these functions be combined into 1?

Comment: The design doesn't make sense. Why can't you use value for both?  And it isn't clear where `obj` comes from.  Any possible solution, imo, would be overly complicated.  Your time would best be served by a redesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you can't modify the `Teacher` and `Student` classes, and make them `implement` a common `interface` (or `extend` a common `class`) which has the `val` / `value` method in it.  If you can, then just do that.

---

You can use *generics* to handle this for you.  A `Function` should cover what you're trying to do here:

```java
public <T, P> T get(final Collection<P> people, 
                    final ToIntFunction<P> valGetter,
                    final Function<P, T> resultGetter) {

    for (final P person : people) {
        if (valGetter.applyAsInt(person) == -1) {
            return resultGetter.apply(person);
        }
    }

    // I don't know, do something?  Throw?
    return null;
}
```

and then invoke it with something like:

```java
final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
get(students, Student::value, Student::name);

final List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
get(teachers, Teacher::val, Teacher::name);
```

---

`ToIntFunction` will take an element of the generic type, and return an `int`.  So for `Student` we just use `Student::value`, and for `Teacher`, use `Teacher::val`.

I can't tell if the `obj.value();` result is the same type, or comes from a common `interface` on both types.  If it does, then you can add `<T, P extends CommonType>` in the generic part, and then just call `.value()` from that.  The answer above assumes it doesn't, and so the `resultGetter` `Function` is used to convert your person-type (`Teacher` or `Student`) to whatever result type that class gives.  I used `::name` in the examples above, but replace that with whatever property you want to pull out from them.

Finally, handle the case when none of them match...  I don't know what's suitable in your case, but `throw new ...Exception` or `return null` seem the two most likely candidates.